# Scripts not loading in jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I want to render the some scripts but it seems they are not loaded in my jade file although the block content gets loaded

Here is the code:

```
script(type='text/javascript' src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.5.0/firebase.js")

script(type='text/javascript' src="/../scripts/main.js")
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}
```

Comment: Have you inspected your `DevTools` => `Network` tab and ensured that it is showing any `404` error(s) for these script inclusions?

Comment: Yea, it's not even making a request for the file

Comment: Have you kept your `script` declarations under `head` ?

Comment: Yea, I figured it out just now, it's working after I keep it under the head.. noob mistake though!

Comment: I will put this as an answer, Can you please accept it? :)

Comment: Yea sure bro, no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to put your `script` tags under `head` block in your `Jade` templates.

Your code should look like,

```
  extends layout
  append head
    script(type='text/javascript' src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.5.0/firebase.js")

    script(type='text/javascript' src="/../scripts/main.js")

    block content
      h1= title
      p Welcome to #{title}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Are you sure it would not throw error? Because I think this is a child template, so it should only define `block`'s. https://pugjs.org/language/inheritance.html#common-mistakes

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj My Bad, I didn't realize that..  In that case we should be using the `append head` keyword (if I'm not wrong).

Comment: Yeah, I think either we need to include the scripts in the parent template i.e. layout.pug in this case. Or if that is not desired for any reason, we can include them inside `block content`, or by creating another block, something like `block footer` etc.